# What does * represent in function argument list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While going through the source code, I noticed the following syntax being used in the asyncio library:

```py
@coroutine
def sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None):
    """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
    if delay == 0:
        yield
        return result

    if loop is None:
        loop = events.get_event_loop()
    future = loop.create_future()
    h = future._loop.call_later(delay,
                                futures._set_result_unless_cancelled,
                                future, result)
    try:
        return (yield from future)
    finally:
        h.cancel()
```

what does the `*` do in the argument list?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It means that parameter(s) that comes after `*` are keyword only parameters.

Consider the following:

```
def test(delay, result=None, *, loop=None):
    print(delay, result, loop)
```

In this case, `test(1,2,2)` will raise `TypeError` since it is expecting *at most* two positional arguments, i.e. `delay` and `result`:

```
test(1,2,2)
```

> TypeError: test() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

The third argument, or *loop*, can only be assigned if used as keyword:

```
test(1,2,loop=2)
# 1 2 2
# Works fine
```

For more detail, refer to [Function Definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)